# border-image had a other behavior on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm currently using border-image on a website to display a better looking textbox.

But the border-image property has a different behavior using firefox than in chrome, edge and safari.

```
.home_nopic {
padding: 15px;
min-height: 120px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 12px;
-moz-border-image: url('../img/content-body.png') 5 12 stretch stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url('../img/content-body.png') 5 12 stretch stretch;
-o-border-image: url('../img/content-body.png') 5 12 stretch stretch;
border-image: url('../img/content-body.png') 5 12 fill stretch stretch;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.75);
font-family: 'Germania One', cursive;
font-size: 1.4em}
```

For testing purposes a small code to show the error I'm getting.

```html
<html>

    <body>

    <div class="home_nopic" style="min-width=80%; font-size: 1.7em; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 217, 179, 0.6); padding: 15px; min-height: 120px;  border-style: solid; border-width: 5px 12px; border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mod4j.png') 5 12 fill stretch stretch; color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.75); font-family: 'Germania One', cursive; font-size: 1.4em">
        Lorem ipsum text
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

[On chrome it looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f2uo.png)

[And in firefox I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XQOd.png)

[content-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mod4j.png)

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: Note: no browser has needed vendor prefixes for `border-image` for quite a few years.

Comment: what is your browser version, it's ok on my side

Comment: I'm currently using firefox version 75.0 (64-Bit).